# How to get the heading like this using powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-cmdlet

I want to get the heading as `"StudentID|studentfirstname|studentlastname|class"` to my existing data as below:

```
2|vicky|kash|A
5|abc|sdf|B
9|sdf|sdf|D
```

My code looks like:

```
add-content -path "outfile.txt" -Value  (-join($StudentID, "|",`
$studentfirstname, "|",` $studentlastname, "|",`$class)
```

Expected output file:

```
StudentID|studentfirstname|studentlastname|class
2|vicky|kash|A
5|abc|sdf|B
9|sdf|sdf|D
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please include your code too

Comment: PLEASE, try to avoid images of code/data/errors when posting here. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Did you try something like this: `Export-Csv -Path .\whatever.csv -Delimiter '|'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not quite sure what you intend to do, but to me the question reads as *"I have pipe-delimited data and all it is missing is a header line"*.
If that is the case, you coud do something as simple as:

```
$fileIn  = 'D:\Test\YourFile.csv'
$fileOut = 'D:\Test\YourFile2.csv'
# write the header line to a new file
Set-Content -Path $fileOut -Value "StudentID|studentfirstname|studentlastname|class"
# read the original file and append it to the one you have just created
Get-Content -Path $fileIn -Raw | Add-Content -Path $fileOut
```

If your input file is *really* large, below a faster alternative:

```
$fileIn  = 'D:\Test\YourFile.csv' 
$fileOut = 'D:\Test\YourFile2.csv'
# write the header line to a new file
Set-Content -Path $fileOut -Value "StudentID|studentfirstname|studentlastname|class"
# read the original file and append it to the one you have just created
[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($fileOut, ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($fileIn)))
```

Answer (score 1):

That syntax is incorrect...
Just do this...

```
$StudentID        = '123'
$studentfirstname = 'John'
$studentlastname  = 'Doe'
$class            = 'Math'


Clear-Host
"$StudentID|$studentfirstname|$studentlastname|$class"
# Results
<#
123|John|Doe|Math
#>
```

Or

```
Clear-Host
$StudentID,$studentfirstname,$studentlastname,$class -join '|'
# Results
<#
123|John|Doe|Math
#>
```

Or

```
Clear-Host
"{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}" -f $StudentID,$studentfirstname,$studentlastname,$class
# Results
<#
123|John|Doe|Math
#>
```